# Difference between const char *p = "some_string" and const char[] = "some_string" in terms of memory allocation

Tags: c++, c, c-strings

```
const char *fun1()
{
    const char *a = "hello";
    return a;
}

const char *fun2()
{
    const char a[] = "hello";
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", fun1());
    printf("%s\n", fun2());
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
cpp:12:12: warning: address of local variable 'a' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   12 |     return a;
      |            ^
passwords.cpp:11:16: note: declared here
   11 |     const char a[] = "hello";
      |                ^
hello
(null)
```

What's difference between these two method of a assigning a string?
I am getting a warning for one while not the other one?
I know local variables get destroyed when we return from a function but why this is not the case with fun1()?
Does it get memory somewhere else instead of stack?

Comment: I actually want to ask that in case of const char *p = "somestring", It persist even after returning from the function, why?
Does that string get memory on heap and pointer on stack?

Comment: Pointers to string literals are valid during the execution of the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the bytes of the string in `fun1()` live in static memory. in the other function the bytes are copied from the static memory into a buffer on the stack on initialization. It is undefined to access the returned string that is returned from `fun2()` because the array on the stack does not exist anymore.

`fun1()` could be rewritten as

```
const char fun1()
{
    static const char s[] = "hello";
    const char* a = s;
    return a;
}
```

`fun2()` could be rewritten as

```
const char fun2()
{
    static const char s[] = "hello";
    const char a[6]; // stack allocation (5 letters + 1 zero terminator)
    strcpy(a, s);
    return a; // UB: return pointer to local automatic array
}
```

So the main reason you get the warning is that the array in `fun2()` does not exist after the call. You return a pointer into the stack frame, in the same way the following code has the same problem:

```
struct S { int x, y; };

struct S* fun1()
{
    static struct S s = { 10, 42 };
    return &s; // no problem
}

struct S* fun2()
{
    struct S a = { 10, 42 };
    return &a; // UB
}
```